# How to prevent hidden album from showing up on CTAssetsPickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I am using CTAssetsPickerController https://github.com/chiunam/CTAssetsPickerController to import images from the photos app. I want to disable importing from the 'Hidden' album some users may have. If you have What's App and a hidden album you'll notice that you can't import from said album. I want to be able to do the same but been searching for hours and haven't gotten anywhere yet. Appreciate your help

```
 - (void)showImagePickerForSourceType:(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType)sourceType {
// Create the image picker
// request authorization status
[PHPhotoLibrary requestAuthorization:^(PHAuthorizationStatus status){
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // init picker
        self.imagePickerController = [[CTAssetsPickerController alloc] init];

        // set delegate
        self.imagePickerController.delegate = self;
        // create options for fetching photo only
        PHFetchOptions *fetchOptions = [PHFetchOptions new];
        fetchOptions.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"mediaType == %d", PHAssetMediaTypeImage];

        // assign options
        self.imagePickerController.assetsFetchOptions = fetchOptions;

        // Optionally present picker as a form sheet on iPad
        if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
            self.imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

        // present picker
        [self presentViewController:self.imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a little more research I found that the framework has a delegate method that enables you to disable assets.

To solve my problem I implemented this method:

```
- (BOOL)assetsPickerController:(CTAssetsPickerController *)picker shouldEnableAsset:(PHAsset *)asset {
     return !asset.isHidden;
}
```

The hidden album still shows up but importing from it is disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the repo for CTAssetsPickerController, it seems you can set the album type by setting a property called `assetCollectionSubtype` to an array of integer values, corresponding to Apple's PHAssetCollectionSubtype enum. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Photos/Reference/PHAssetCollection_Class/#//apple_ref/c/tdef/PHAssetCollectionSubtype